# Getting error: Test webhook error: 400 when trying to send a test event to a webhook endpoint

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, stripe-payments

I am attempting to [send a test webhook](https://ibb.co/vYtNjYJ) as instructed in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@GaryHarrower/working-with-stripe-webhooks-firebase-cloud-functions-5366c206c6c).

But when I go to do it I get the error seen in the first link, and below:

> Test webhook error: 400

Here is my index.ts code & functions I have deployed to firebase functions.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
​
​
// const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().keys.webhooks);
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
​
admin.initializeApp();
const endpointSecret = functions.config().keys.signing;
​
exports.events = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
​
  let sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];
​
  try {
    
    let event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody, sig, endpointSecret); // Validate the request
    
    return admin.database().ref('/events').push(event) // Add the event to the database
      .then((snapshot: { ref: { toString: () => any; }; }) => {
        // Return a successful response to acknowledge the event was processed successfully
        return response.json({ received: true, ref: snapshot.ref.toString() });
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        console.error(err) // Catch any errors saving to the database
        return response.status(500).end();
      });
  }
  catch (err) {
    return response.status(400).end(); // Signing signature failure, return an error 400
  }
  
});
​
exports.exampleDatabaseTrigger = functions.database.ref('/events/{eventId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  return console.log({
    eventId: context.params.eventId,
    data: snapshot.val()
  });
});
```

**How do I fix this and successfully run the test?**

My current thinking is that the problem may have something to do with:

How I wrote this line: `snapshot: { ref: { toString: () => any; };`

### Update:

From my testing, this does not appear to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that the 'test webhook' properly signs them; you should use [Stripe CLI](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli) for this instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66662013/stripe-login-zsh-command-not-found-stripe?noredirect=1#comment117842974_66662013