# stripe login zsh: command not found: stripe

Tags: macos, terminal, stripe-payments

I'm following [stripes docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli#install) and when I go to `stripe login` in step 2, I get the following error:

> zsh: command not found: stripe

I already performed step 1, installing the stripe CLI, **Why am I getting this error?**

### Update, Update2: I performed the recommended actions, but stripe login still does not work.

I realized, that I am getting the following error for step 1: (Check update2)

```
nmaer@nmaer-MBP SignUpFlowFanclub % brew install stripe/stripe-cli/stripe
Error: 
  homebrew-core is a shallow clone.
To `brew update`, first run:
  git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow
This command may take a few minutes to run due to the large size of the repository.
This restriction has been made on GitHub's request because updating shallow
clones is an extremely expensive operation due to the tree layout and traffic of
Homebrew/homebrew-core and Homebrew/homebrew-cask. We don't do this for you
automatically to avoid repeatedly performing an expensive unshallow operation in
CI systems (which should instead be fixed to not use shallow clones). Sorry for
the inconvenience!
Ignoring ffi-1.12.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.12.2
==> Installing stripe from stripe/stripe-cli
==> Downloading https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/releases/download/v1.5.9/stripe_1.5.9_mac-os_x86_64.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/nmaer/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/afda22020bd67ba6a51e1c4420ec72f009db3462b48c7675b83b1fa0b77928af--stripe_1.5.9_mac-os_x86_64.tar.gz
Ignoring ffi-1.12.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.12.2
Error: Your Command Line Tools (CLT) does not support macOS 11.
It is either outdated or was modified.
Please update your Command Line Tools (CLT) or delete it if no updates are available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.

Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  SystemExit: exit
```

Comment: Have you followed the error message's directions to run the two commands under `If that doesn't show you any updates, run:`?

Comment: @taintedzodiac it did show updates, and I update. Still have the issue.

Comment: What's the output of that command now that you installed the command line tools from xcode? It should be different.

Comment: softwareupdate: Software Update Tool

Finding available software
Downloading macOS Big Sur 11.2.3

Downloaded: macOS Big Sur 11.2.3 @taintedzodiac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I re-installed [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) by running:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Then I ran `brew install stripe/stripe-cli/stripe` again, and this time it worked without any problems.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the answer is a bit late for you, but I also spent some time on it and share my solution to the problem.

You can also install Stripe without a package manager. On the new Mac with M1 chip there are problems with the path.

Download the latest release
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/releases/tag/v1.7.13

Then move the unzipped file to the `/usr/local/bin` folder and you can use the stripe commands again

Comment: Moving to the /usr/local/bin resolved the issue. Thanks