# command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I'm getting the error you see below:

```
    xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
    Name@Name-MBP SignUpFlowFanclub % Software Update
    zsh: command not found: Software
    Name@Name-MBP SignUpFlowFanclub %
```

[This error is coming up as I try and install stripe CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66662013/stripe-login-zsh-command-not-found-stripe?noredirect=1#comment117842974_66662013).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to update Xcode.
You try `softwareupdate --install -a`,

if you have problem, use this:
`xcode-select --install`.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue:

> scntool: warning: Could not find bundle inside
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools  at path
> /Library/Developer/SharedFrameworks/ModelIO.framework

Maybe Homebrew or something caused the issue - not sure

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

did help

Comment: Did you mean "Homebrew", not "Hebrew"?

Comment: not work, already the message 'use "Software Update" to install updates'

Answer (score 7):

1. sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
2. xcode-select --install

From https://github.com/joyfulee/daGit/issues/2

Answer (score 2):

I recently updated to MacOS Big Sur version 11.2.3 and found that I had to manually install the Xcode SDK tools from the apple developer site: https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_12.4/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_12.4.dmg in order to successfully install packages using MacPorts. But even after installing the Xcode_12.4 I still got the same warning messages:
Warning: The macOS 11.2 SDK does not appear to be installed. Ports may not build correctly.
Warning: You can install it as part of the Xcode Command Line Tools package by running `xcode-select --install'.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to leave this here in case someone has the same problems as I did. There seems to be a bit of an issue after a recent MacOS update. I found this thread which helped me get past the issue of not being able to install the command line tools while repeatedly asking me to install them: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415563/repeatedly-being-asked-to-install-command-line-tools

Essentially, run:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same boat as Greg W. You need an apple account to access the developer tools. I dont know what macports is but homebrew is having trouble updating because it cant find the xcode sdk. Pyenv specifically.