# Stripe customers create using stripe CLI not resulting in change in firebase database?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stripe-payments

I have been following [this firebase + stripe tutorial](https://medium.com/@GaryHarrower/working-with-stripe-webhooks-firebase-cloud-functions-5366c206c6c) with some exceptions. Like: I am using [Stripe CLI](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli) instead of the [method for testing used in the tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66648534/getting-error-test-webhook-error-400-when-trying-to-send-a-test-event-to-a-web).

I have tried then to test my code like in the tutorial. Try and run a `stripe customers create` command in the console, it produces a healthy log:

```
 {
  "id": "cus_J8SNcOZtsuXqb4",
  "object": "customer",
  "address": null,
  "balance": 0,
  "created": 1616033987,
  "currency": null,
  "default_source": null,
  "delinquent": false,
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "email": null,
  "invoice_prefix": "16D3BF86",
  "invoice_settings": {
    "custom_fields": null,
    "default_payment_method": null,
    "footer": null
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "name": null,
  "next_invoice_sequence": 1,
  "phone": null,
  "preferred_locales": [

  ],
  "shipping": null,
  "tax_exempt": "none"
}
```

When this happens the realtime database on firebase should be updated. But it's not, this is the problem.

**Why is the realtime database not responding to the stripe command?**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you set up your webhook URLs to point to your Firebase application as described in the tutorial?

Comment: I think the answer is yes according to what I see on its settings take a look: https://ibb.co/LQXbS76

Comment: I noticed in the screenshot that customer.created was missing. So I added it but with the same results.

Comment: If you added the webhook endpoint afterwards, you may want to retry the whole process.